# "You could never tell me the odds" as an idiom of improbability

Tags: expressions, idioms, idiom-requests

I'm currently writing a small essay for my English class and I'd like to know if this sentence would work as an idiom of improbability

> You could never tell me the odds when I noticed that this small coffee shop had a "Now Hiring" sign just outside their window.

I'm trying to find an idiom to express the astonishment I had when I realised a very improbable event. (For context I was looking for a job, I went in a small coffee shop to look for offers on my phone when I realised that said coffee shop was currently hiring, and subsequently got hired.)

I tried to look up if "never tell me the odds" was a common saying, but it doesn't seem like anyone outside of the Star Wars and Reddit universe uses it regularly.

Comment: My advice is "don't use it". It does not make any sense.

Comment: "What a coincidence!" is an exclamatory phrase that (roughly) captures what you're going for here.

Comment: It's not an idiom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could not find much usage of "You could never tell me the odds..." then it is unlikely to be idiomatic (and it isn't).

I suggest:

> What were the chances of there being a "Now Hiring" sign on the coffee shop window?

Google [Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=What+were+the+chances+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWhat%20were%20the%20chances%20of%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CWhat%20were%20the%20chances%20of%3B%2Cc0) shows:

[image]

Comment: Would "Imagine my surpise when I realised..." also work in a similar sense?

Comment: Yes, that would work. Of course, my answer poses the sentence as a *rhetorical* question.